# How to call curl in php?

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I have try to call below command in using php but its give blank response so please anyone help to call below command in php.

```
curl -v -u [email]:[token] -X GET https://api.coolrunner.dk/v1/me
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this curl class

- [php curl class](https://github.com/lepunk/curl.class.php/blob/master/curl.class.php)

There is a sample :

```
include 'curl.class.php';

$curl = new Curl();

try {
    $respones = $curl->get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
    var_dump($respones);
    $result = json_decode($respones);
    echo "<br />Title : ".$result->title;
}catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo $curl->getError();
}
```

I think this is a sample for your request :

```
include 'curl.class.php';

$curl = new Curl();

$email = 'test@example.com';
$token = 'kaiDklasdfSDFv6adsfvjhsadr';
try {
    $curl->setBasicAuth($email,$token);
    $respones = $curl->get('https://api.coolrunner.dk/v1/me');
    var_dump($respones);
}catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo $curl->getError();
}
```

Comment: @ashishmulani can you give me a documentation of your api ?

Comment: you can use this $curl->setBasicAuth($email,$token); and after this you can call  $response = $curl->get('https://api.coolrunner.dk/v1/me');
the $response variable is your resulte

Comment: what is the advantage of using a third-party class instead of the built-in curl support (since PHP PHP 4.0.2)?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch This is simple and work fine ! php curl is very difficult !

Answer (score 0):

PHP has cURL functions, check the documentation: [PHP: cURL Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php)